# How to know/ check a requested page is a sub row or sub-sub row in a db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I know/ check a requested page/ row is a sub row or sub-sub row?

For instance, this is my page table,

```
pg_id   pg_url  pg_title    parent_id
1       a       a           1
2       b       b           2
3       aa      aa          1
4       aaa     aaa         3
```

`pg_id 3` is a **sub** page as its parent is `pg_id 1`, while `pg_id 4` is a **sub-sub** page as its parent is `pg_id 3`

Here is my query how I get the info usually,

```
SELECT 
p.pg_id, 
p.pg_url,
p.parent_id

FROM root_pages AS p
WHERE p.pg_id = '4'
```

but it does not give info whether this requested is a sub or sub-sub page.

is any way to achieve this with a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would want something like this:

```
SELECT 
p.pg_id, 
p.pg_url,
p.parent_id,
p2.pg_id as 'ParentPageID',
p3.pg_id as 'GrandparentPageID'

FROM root_pages AS p
LEFT JOIN root_pages AS p2 on p.parent_id = p2.pg_id AND p.pg_id <> p2.pg_id
LEFT JOIN root_pages AS p3 on p2.parent_id = p3.pg_id AND p2.pg_id <> p3.pg_id
WHERE p.pg_id = '4'
```

If the grandparent page ID isn't null, it's a sub-sub page.  If it is, but the parent page ID isn't null, it's a sub-page.

Comment: can I ask - what does this symbol `<>` means?

Comment: It's a not equal operator, it's equivalent to !=

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(p.pg_id == p.parent_id,'true','false') AS 'top_level',
IF(sub_page.pg_id IS NOT NULL,'true','false') AS 'sub_level',
IF(sub_sub_page.pg_id IS NOT NULL,'true','false') AS 'sub_sub_level',
p.pg_id, 
p.pg_url,
p.parent_id
FROM root_pages AS p
LEFT JOIN p AS sub_page ON sub_page.pg_id = p.parent_id AND p.parent_id != p.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN p AS sub_sub_page ON sub__sub_page.pg_id = sub_page.parent_id AND sub_page.parent_id != sub_page.parent_id 
WHERE p.pg_id = '4'
```

Should probably work

Comment: thanks Kasia, but I have this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== p.parent_id,'true','false') AS 'top_level', IF(sub_page.pg_id IS NOT NULL,'t' at line 1`

Comment: sorry the double = needs removing :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then if parent_id = pg_id for a given row, then that row is a parent to itself, and is not a 'sub page' or a 'sub-sub page'.

If you're looking to find the exact *level* a page is at, you will need to use recursion or a recursive query.  Below just performs the recursion in PHP, but using a recursive query would be more efficient.

```
   function findLevel($root, $current, $level) {
       if($root == $current) return $level;
       $parent = mysql_fetch_array($db->query(
           'SELECT parent_id FROM page WHERE pg_id = ?', 
           array( $current )));
       return findLevel($root, $parent['parent_id'], $level+1);      
   }

   $pageLevel = findLevel(1, 4, 0);  // Finds the the level for the id '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
    p.pg_id, 
    p.pg_url,
    p.parent_id,
    IF(
         p.parent_id =1,
        'sub page',
        'sub sub page'
    ) as page_type
    r.parent_id as root page    
FROM root_pages AS p
LEFT JOIN root_pages AS r
    ON r.pg_id = p.parent_id
WHERE p.pg_id = '4'
```

But this is a static example i mean it works for 2 cases : sub page and sub sub page but for n cases you need a different aproach

Comment: thanks Stephan, but I have this error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'r.parent_id as root page FROM root_pages AS p LEFT JOIN root_pages AS r ' at line 10`...

Comment: i forgot to add comma (,) after 'as page_type' sorry :)